# Looping the columns from Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have the dataframe and I want to use function baseline correction.

The code below is what I have done for one column but I want to do every column for 1 time by looping. How can I do it?

```
df=pd.read_csv('datatest.csv')
y=df['column1']
x=df.index
baseline_filter = Baseline(x_data=x)
bli1= baseline_filter.adaptive_minmax(y, poly_order=None, method='modpoly', weights=None, constrained_fraction=0.001, constrained_weight=100000.0, estimation_poly_order=2, method_kwargs=None)[0]
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(bli1)`
```

I did this code but it does not work.

```
for i in df:
    x=df.index
    baseline_filter = Baseline(x_data=x)
    bli1= baseline_filter.adaptive_minmax(i, poly_order=None, method='modpoly', weights=None, constrained_fraction=0.001, constrained_weight=100000.0, estimation_poly_order=3, method_kwargs=None)[0]
   ValueError: length mismatch for data; expected 1433 but got 1
```

How can I use the loop for this function?

Sometimes the error displayed

```
ValueError: must be a one dimensional array
```

When I coded following your suggestion, the error has shown like this. I have to use the bli1 to plot baseline. How can I fix this?

```
for i in df:
        for j in df[i]:
            baseline_filter = Baseline(x_data=j)
            bli1= baseline_filter.adaptive_minmax(j, poly_order=None, method='modpoly', weights=None, constrained_fraction=0.001, constrained_weight=100000.0, estimation_poly_order=3, method_kwargs=None)[0]
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your dataframe's columns like so:

```
# Loop through each column
for x in df:
    # Loop through each element per column
    for j in df[i]:
        baseline_filter = Baseline(x_data=j)
```

You incorrectly called `df.index`, which does not
change as you iterate through your `df`. The only
thing that changes is your `i` variable. Essentially, you were trying to call your `Baseline` function on a fixed [integer range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your advises, however, I coded following yours. It is still some error as shown in the answer box. Could you have further suggestions?

Comment: @TCC You probably have null values in your `df`. I would recommend using `df.dropna(inplace=True)` to remove null values.

Comment: Thank you I used df.dropna(inplace=True) but it was still the same error. I think the problem may come from the input of bli1 before poly_order.